# How do I make text in a cell bold based on its cell fill color?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, custom-function

What formula (if any) I would use if I wanted to make text with a specific fill color to become bold? For example, if a cell's fill is gray and I want the text inside of every gray cell to be bold.

I looked through the conditional formatting presets but I couldn't find anything that was similar to what I wanted to do.

Comment: Is there a specificication of the target range? Or just the whole worksheet?

Comment: @player0, maybe OP has tagged Excel for a reason? I wouldn't just get rid of the tag tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to include color in the conditional.

Other suggestions that might get you what you wanted:
1. Most spreadsheet color formatting is related to another value (such as temperature, where "red" corresponded to >40 C). If that's the case, you could use conditionals on that value.
2. You could work with a styles manager, such as the third-party add-in "Table Styles". See this [tutorial](https://www.ablebits.com/docs/google-sheets-apply-table-styles/) for a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. you will need to use a script like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var bg;

  for(var i=1; i<data1.length; i++)
  {
    bg = sheet1.getRange(i+1, 2).getBackground();
    if(bg == "#555555") {s.getRange(row+1,1).setFontWeight("bold")}    
  }
}
```

which should bold out text in Sheet1 in every cell that has gray shade #555555